# Convert String to date R spanish

Tags: r, string, date

I am reading some information from a csv, it has a field called date but it is a String with this format:
ID,"Date","PM25","PM10","TEMP"
-1,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 7:10",24,25,25.8
2,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 9:13",19,21,24.4
3,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 14:55",32,37,28.1
4,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 15:06",34,39,29.2
5,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 15:17",34,38,29.6
6,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 15:27",33,37,29.6
7,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 15:38",31,33,29.0
8,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 15:49",29,33,28.8
9,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 16:00",30,32,28.8
10,"miércoles, 20 de febrero de 2019, 16:11",28,29,28.4

I want to convert the String to date and create a new column with the format dd-mm-yyyy, for that I am using this instruction:

```
datos <- read.csv("Registros.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = F)

datos$Fechas <- as.Date(datos$Fecha, "%d %B %Y")
```

But i am just getting NA as a result.

I change it manually to "20 de febrero de 2019" but it still returns NA

I also tried with lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
datos$Fechas <- dmy(datos$Fecha)
```

But i get this warning and also NA as a result:
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close; however, when you have also minutes and seconds inside the same string you can use `dmy_hm` instead of `dmy` to convert the string into a Date. Afterwards, you can use `stamp` to set the desired format for your date. Here is a way of doing it using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Set the desired format as stamp dd-mm-yyyy
my_stamp<-stamp( "20-02-2019", orders = "dmy") 

df %>%
  #Convert Date column to Date using dmy_hm
  mutate_at(vars(Date), function(x) dmy_hm(x)) %>%
  #Create new column with the desired format for the date
  mutate(formattedDate = my_stamp(Date))


# ID                Date PM25 PM10 TEMP formattedDate
# 1  -1 2019-02-20 07:10:00   24   25 25.8    20-02-2019
# 2   2 2019-02-20 09:13:00   19   21 24.4    20-02-2019
# 3   3 2019-02-20 14:55:00   32   37 28.1    20-02-2019
# 4   4 2019-02-20 15:06:00   34   39 29.2    20-02-2019
# 5   5 2019-02-20 15:17:00   34   38 29.6    20-02-2019
# 6   6 2019-02-20 15:27:00   33   37 29.6    20-02-2019
# 7   7 2019-02-20 15:38:00   31   33 29.0    20-02-2019
# 8   8 2019-02-20 15:49:00   29   33 28.8    20-02-2019
# 9   9 2019-02-20 16:00:00   30   32 28.8    20-02-2019
# 10 10 2019-02-20 16:11:00   28   29 28.4    20-02-2019
```

Comment: Thanks so much it worked properly i got what I need